# How to log user in FastAPI requests

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

I am trying to log all my FastAPI requests (who requested, what and what is the status code) by creating a custom `APIRoute`-class. This is my custom Route-class:

```py
class LoggingRoute(APIRoute):
    def get_route_handler(self) -> Callable:
        original_route_handler = super().get_route_handler()

        async def custom_route_handler(request: Request) -> Response:
            response: Response = await original_route_handler(request)
            log_request(
                user = request.user,
                url = request.url,
                method = request.method,
                status_code = response.status_code
            )
            return response

        return custom_route_handler
```

The logging would work if we don't want to include `request.user` to the logs. When trying to access the user, the following error is thrown:

`AssertionError: AuthenticationMiddleware must be installed to access request.user`

I guess the user-attribute of the request is not yet initialized inside the route handler. `request.user` works well when handling the request later.

My question is: is there any way for me to get access to `request.user` inside the `custom_route_handler`-function? If not, is there another way to implement the logging functionality with ability to log the user as well?

Comment: In what order do you register the middlewares?

Comment: @MatsLindh I followed this guide to setup the authentication: https://intility.github.io/fastapi-azure-auth/single-tenant/fastapi_configuration

It seems that there's just the CORSMiddleware registered when starting the app.

Answer (score 0):

You must install `AuthenticationMiddleware`.

> https://www.starlette.io/authentication/#users
> Once AuthenticationMiddleware is installed the request.user interface will be available to endpoints or other middleware.

```py
app = FastAPI(middleware=[Middleware(AuthenticationMiddleware)])
```